# What happened to: "What benefits are there to native JavaScript development?"?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, questions, deleted-questions

I was reading [this question and answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122191/what-benefits-are-there-to-native-javascript-development) this morning and I noticed it disappeared now and I get an error page with "removed for reasons of moderation"

What happened to the question and why?

I recall it having 6K views and some activity today (A friend of mine wrote a popular answer there and he pinged me surprised that it got attention).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've fixed this.

The question was originally migrated here from Stack Overflow in November 2011. It was closed today (3 September 2014) by 5 members of the community as being "primarily opinion based", which I agree with. However, when I was cleaning up other rejected migrations that were not adding value, I got over-zealous and accidentally deleted this one too.

I undeleted the post, cleared the migration history (to make it seem like it was always a Programmers question), and reclosed for the reason that the community elected to close it as.

From now, the community can vote to reopen (with 5 votes, as normal) or delete normally. Answers and the question body can be edited and commented on.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for the undelete - both are appreciated. I also understand (and agree) that it's opinion based in 2014 standards.

Comment: Oh - by the way, the reason I got to it in the first place is being told it got a lot of attention today: Given that diamond mods have access to analytics data - any change of learning where the traffic came from?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum We can't reveal any of the analytics data. It probably got posted on a high-volume blog or link sharing site.

Comment: Fair enough, didn't think the referral link would be confidential. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Other than super secret, mod analytics are also pretty useless. We don't have any info for individual posts (related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77138/162704).